# Closing a child window (in another process) is closing the parent window

Tags: .net, winforms

The situation is a little unusual because the child form is in different process:

1. The parent window is the only form in process "A".
2. When a Run button is clicked, a new process "B" is started and the parent
   window handle is passed as a command line argument.

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo command = new ProcessStartInfo();
   string thisProgramsPath = (new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;
   command.FileName = thisProgramsPath;
   command.UseShellExecute = false; // Prevents "Publisher cannot be verified" in Citrix.
   // Command Line Args
   StringBuilder args = new StringBuilder();
   if (ParentWorkerCheckbox.Checked) args.AppendFormat("-p {0} ", this.Handle);
   command.Arguments = args.ToString();
   Process.Start(command);
   ```
3. Process B creates a worker form that displays the progress of a long running process. It is shown using ShowDialog and parented to the main form from process A.

   ```
   NativeWindow parent = new NativeWindow();
   parent.AssignHandle(pointer);
   form.ShowDialog(parent);
   ```
4. When the work is complete, a Close button is shown on the worker form.  When clicked, the DialogResult is set, closing the form.

   ```
   private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Owner = null;
       this.DialogResult = _result;
   }
   ```
5. The main form in process A also closes and the application exits!

I can show the worker form without parenting it to the main form and then close it without closing the main form, but I would prefer to parent it so that it always stays on top of the main form.

I don't understand why the main form is closed when the child form closes, since that is not the behavior when the child form closes when parented within the same process. Does anyone know why it behaves this way and/or how to stop it from closing the main form?

Comment: If I use `form.Show(parent);` to show the processing form, the main form closes and the application exits immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `NativeWindow`, try using this:

```
private class SimpleWindow : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window {
    IntPtr h = IntPtr.Zero;
    public SimpleWindow(IntPtr ptr) {
        h = ptr;
    }
    public IntPtr Handle {
        get { return h; }
    }
}
```

My guess is part of the cleanup process when second process exits is to cleanup any assigned handles.